# How can I convert LaTeX to MathML using c# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, latex, mathml

I would like to convert LaTeX to MathML using vb.net or C#. How can I do so?

I have found and tried the project [latex2mathml](https://latex2mathml.codeplex.com/), but it doesn't work.

While debugging the code I can see that it is searching for something that will always give no information back and it doesn't create the MathML expression.

in the solution you can find the Pase method. 
in the place where you build the paragraph i can find the next code:

```
 // Build paragraph blocks
        LogInfo("BuildParagraphs");
        BuildParagraphs(Root.FindDocument().Expressions[0], customization);
        OnProgressEvent(step++, PASS_COUNT);
```

the Root.FindDocument looks like:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Find the document block in children (valid only for the root expression).
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public LatexExpression FindDocument()
    {
        if (ExprType != ExpressionType.Root) return null;
        LatexExpression documentExpression = null;
        foreach (var child in Expressions[0])
        {
            if (child.ExprType == ExpressionType.Block && child.Name == "document")
            {
                documentExpression = child;
                break;
            }
        }
        return documentExpression;
    }
```

with the next latex example:
"\cos (2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta" the expression is:

```
[0]: {(0) [Command] cos}
  [1]: {(0) [PlainText]  (2}
  [2]: {(0) [Command] theta}
  [3]: {(0) [PlainText] ) = }
  [4]: {(0) [Command] cos}
  [5]: {(0) [PlainText] ^2 }
  [6]: {(0) [Command] theta}
  [7]: {(0) [PlainText]  - }
  [8]: {(0) [Command] sin}
  [9]: {(0) [PlainText] ^2 }
  [10]: {(0) [Command] theta}
```

when the search result is null i get an exaption on the line  Root.FindDocument().Expressions[0]

Thank You

Ori

Comment: "it is searching for something that will always give no information back" - could you please go more in detail? Eventually add some code excerpts and/or error messages.

Comment: If you use the default log4net config file which comes with the library there should be a "log.txt" file created which might tell you more about the problem.

Comment: thank you for your replay. I have updated the question with more info.

Comment: This is the source code of the library. Actually we need to see your calling code. It should be something like "LatexToMathMLConverter converter = new LatexToMathMLConverter(SOURCEPATH, Encoding.UTF8, OUTPUTPATH);". I tried to convert a minimum .tex file to a .mml file and it worked just fine.

Comment: the calling code is:   var lmm = new LatexToMathMLConverter(
                @"C:\Codeplex\latex2mathml\source.txt",
                Encoding.GetEncoding(1251),
                @"C:\Codeplex\latex2mathml\result.xml");
            lmm.ValidateResult = true;
            lmm.Convert();

Comment: What does your source.txt file look like? Does it work when you use a minimun file instead like:
"\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\cos (2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta$
\end{document}"

Comment: my txt file looks like: \cos (2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta  took it from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Comment: I have tested the solution with your text and it works fine. he is looking for the 'document' element in the latex expression which i don’t have in my latex expressions. Thank you for your answer